# A question regarding differentiability and the boundary of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity, analytic-functions

Consider a Jordan curve $\Gamma\subset \mathbb{C}$ and let $\Omega$ be the interior of $\Gamma$ (which is well-defined by the Jordan curve theorem). Let $f:\Gamma\cup\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be analytic on $\Omega$ and continuous on $\Gamma$. Given these assumptions, does it hold that the limit

$$\lim_{w\rightarrow z}\frac{f(z)-f(w)}{z-w}$$

exists for each $z \in \Gamma$ (with $w \in \Gamma\cup\Omega$)? So basically I am asking if $f$ has a derivative on $\Gamma$ in an appropriately understood sense.

Comment: no - for example, on the unit disc, one needs $f'$ to be on $H^1$ (it is if and only if actually if you only require the existence of radial derivative ae and its equality with the circle derivative which also exists ae) and that is a strong condition (eg take $f(z)=\sum z^{2^n}/2^n$ which has the unit circle as natural boundary, and it is trivially continuous there, but $f'$ is far from being in $H^1$;

Comment: This is unfortunate, but quite frankly not that surprising. Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: happy to be of help; continuity on the boundary is a very weak condition in general